# Can you not combine CSS styles into a single line of code (that are effected by a hover)?

Tags: html, css

Why can I not combine these into a single line, when I do it only effects the latter. On hover of .link, I want h3 and h4 to be color:white. Example:


This works, but I wanted to save a line of code by combining them.

```
.link:hover h3 {
 color: white;
}

.link:hover h4 {
color: white;
}
```

However this does not work, it only effects the h3, and the h4 color:white gets applied before the hover

```
.link:hover h3, h4 {
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not applying the second one on hover!

```
.link:hover h3 ,
.link:hover h4 {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a note, if you *really* wanted the capability to apply the style to both `h3` and `h4` without having to repeat `.link:hover`, all of the popular CSS preprocessors support that feature. The following works in [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) (SCSS syntax), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), and [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/):

```css
.link:hover {
    h3, h4 {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

That compiles to this CSS (possibly formatted differently):

```css
.link:hover h3,
.link:hover h4 {
    color: white;
}
```